# Change return types for Spring openapi-generator-maven-plugin generated interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I've managed to generate the interfaces from a .yaml open-api descriptor file, but, as in the question title, I'd love to change the response type of those interfaces from ResponseEntity to my own types. Basically instead of the interface having this signature:

```
 ResponseEntity<Void> clearCache();
```

for a method that is implemented basically this way:

```
public void clearCache(){ //do something}
```

I'd want the generated interface to be as simply as

```
void clearCache();
```

Same thing for my own defined classes, instead of `ResponseEntity<MyBook> getBook(String ISBN);` I want it to just use `MyBook` as return type, so it should look something like `MyBook getBook(String ISBN);`
The current settings I'm using for the openapi-generator plugin are

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>my-own-service-be/src/main/resources/api-docs.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <additionalProperties>
                             <additionalProperty>skipDefaultInterface=true</additionalProperty>
                            <additionalProperty>interfaceOnly=true</additionalProperty>
                        </additionalProperties>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <apiPackage>controller</apiPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>false</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <modelPackage>dto</modelPackage>
                        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: There is no way to configure this.

Comment: please open an issue in https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator so that the openapi-generator community can help you out. you may need to customize the templates to achieve what you want

Answer (score 6):

We had a similar challenge recently. What you need to do is to adjust the template. To do so you will need to find the source template from the OpenAPI project for your generator. That would be [this `api.mustache` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/api.mustache) in your case.

Just copy it over to e.g. your `src/main/resources/` folder (maybe in a subfolder named `custom`) and adapt it according to your needs, i.e. replace the response type.

Then you will need to adapt your `pom.xml` such that your custom template file is actually used:

```
     <configuration>

        <!-- The following line is crucial: -->
        <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/custom</templateDirectory>

        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
        <configOptions>
            <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
        </configOptions>
    </configuration>
```

Also have a look at [this templating documentation](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/) for more information on the subject.

Comment: For jaxrs-spec apiInterface.mustache worked for interface generation.

Comment: I had downloaded api.mustache from openApi github repo. and copied to under this directory /src/main/resources/customTemplate . 

It raises compliation error  couldnt find a subtemplate cookieParams.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do that. You can imagine the ResponseEntity simply as wrapper for your type, adding the possibility to handle standard HTTP features like HTTP status code and headers. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity) for further details.
In your case, you would only do

```
ResponseEntity.noContent().build(); //void

ResponseEntity.ok(myBook) //to return your MyBook type
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by philonous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562046/1651107) is step in good direction. All templates for Spring Boot can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring). But changing only "api.mustache" is not enough because "api.moustache" does not contain template for default method implementation. You have to either disable generation of default method implementation or change template for it too.

So as already described, you have to specify templating directory in pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
 <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/custom</templateDirectory>
 <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
```

**Step 1 - api.mustache**:

Here remove "import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;", just to make sure it is not used anymore.
Then remove ResponseEntity from return type by replacing "ResponseEntity<{{>returnTypes}}>" with "{{>returnTypes}}".
Problem is this still generates default implementation with "return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);" in generated Api classes, so we have to change other templates.

**Step 2 - disable default method generation or change methodBody.mustache**:

Disable generation of default implementation with "skipDefaultInterface" option (as shown up in pom.xml).
Otherwise edit "methodBody.mustache" add "throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not implemented");//" in front of "return new ResponseEntity<>" or do something else to indicate method is not implemented yet.